# Cloud Image SSH Login

Tags: 14.04, ssh, login, openstack

I am using OpenStack and when I attempt to login to Ubuntu QCOW2 image it just times out.

I can ping the instance, and I can telnet the SSH port without an issue (`telnet <floating ip> 22`) so I know connectivity isn't my issue.

I am **NOT** using a keypair, I am attempting to login to the VM using what ever the default user info is, but I don't get a message telling me the login is in correct, I just get a timeout (`Operation timed out`).

I attempted to connect via Console in OpenStack but since I don't know the default username/password I can't login there either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default rules that come with the Openstack security policy appear to make everything wide open but I am finding that's just not the case.  I had to manually add all the Egress and Ingress ports I needed before everything was working properly.  So in this case, it appears to be 100% related to the openstack security policy I was using on the instance